# Why do we need a token when authenticating with React/Redux?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, passport.js

I'm building a MERN (Mongo, Express, React/Redux, Node) web app, and I'm implementing authentication on the server with passport.js.

I keep on reading that the server needs to send a token the client.

However, when using React/Redux, I don't see the point. Here's how I implemented it:
1. User clicks submit on register form
2. Data is passed to backend
3. Back end handles authentication with passport
4. If no error, server sends a user object back to client. If error, server sends error message to client.
5. If no error, client stores user object in redux state (and local storage) - so now we know that this user is authenticated.
6. When user wants to do anything that requires being authenticated, the app checks redux state and local storage to see if the user is authenticated.
7. When user logs out, change redux state - say that there is no authenticated user, and remove the user object from local storage.

Why do I need a token here? Is there a concept I'm missing?

I'm not sure if code is necessary here, but here's some of the code:

Front End: Actions.js

```
export const registerUser = formData => dispatch => {
  console.log("In action Register User");
  console.log("Here is the formData: ", formData);
  dispatch(registerRequest()); // Set Loading to true
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:3001/register', formData)
    .then(response => {
      // save user to local storage here
      dispatch(registerSuccess(response.data)); // response.data is user
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(registerFail(err));
    });
};
```

Front End: Auth_Reducer.js

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.REGISTER_REQUEST:
      return updateObject(state, { loading: true });
    case actionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return updateObject(state, {
        loading: false,
        auth_error: '',
        auth_user: action.user
      });
    case actionTypes.REGISTER_FAIL:
      console.log('Register fail');
      return updateObject(state, {
        loading: false,
        auth_user: null,
        auth_error: action.error
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Back End: Auth.js Route

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-register', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else if (info) {
      res.status(400).json(info);
    } else {
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).json(err);
        } else {
          res.json(req.user);
        }
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Your solution implies that the backend doesn't verify the authentication of requests. So I can just ditch the app, speak directly with the backend and do whatever I want without login.

Comment: It does though, with passport. So for example, when a user attempts to access a route that only an authenticated user can access, passport first checks if the user is authenticated?

Comment: But the backend somehow must be able to check the authentication. Which it does by a token you previously acquired by authenticating. Without a token it doesn't know who is making the request